SwiftData propertiesToFetch Ignored in FetchDescriptor, Returns Entire Model
I'm using SwiftData's propertiesToFetch in a FetchDescriptor to limit the fetched properties, but it still returns the entire model with all of its properties.
Here's a simple example of my code
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

 @Model
 class Person: CustomStringConvertible {
    @Attribute(.unique)
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var age: Int?

    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }

    var description: String {
        "Person name: \(name) age: \(age)"
    }
 }

@Observable
class ViewModel {
    init() {
        fetch()
    }

    func fetch() {
        let container = try! ModelContainer(for: Person.self)

        do {
            let context = ModelContext(container)
            let person = Person(name: "Joe", age: 30)
            context.insert(person)

            var fetch = FetchDescriptor<Person>(sortBy: [SortDescriptor(\.name, order: .reverse)])
            fetch.propertiesToFetch = [\.name]
            let people = try context.fetch(fetch)
            print(people) // output [Person name: Joe age: 30]

        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }
}


I tried this property sometime ago but I could never get it to work. But of course your tried solution could never work because you have omitted properties that are not optional from your selection, how could an instance of Person be created without values for all mandatory properties?

Thanks! I tried using optional properties, but it still doesn't work.

Well thee big question for me is what this property is meant to be used for and then how to use it.

Since this is SwiftUI remove the legacy class ViewModel and use @Query. In SwiftUI the View structs are the view model already. propertiesToFetch is just the initial properties e.g. to speed up List rows, print will perform more fetches to for the other properties.
